# catalog_category_product_index_store1 has stopped updating on reindex

Tags: magento2, product, reindex, magento2.2.4

I am currently having issues with making products display when adding them to new categories.

The table `catalog_category_product_index_store1` is no longer adding new records when reindexing

Has anyone faced this issue before and know of a fix?